# SystemModStamp not updated after field type changed

Tags: api, etl, systemmodstamp

After changing the type of a field from "Rich Text" to "Plain Text", Salesforce automatically stripped out the HTML tags used to style the values (e.g. from `<p>Test value<p>` to `Test Value`). *However*, it doesn't appear to have updated the `SystemModStamp` value for these records. Is this expected?

Comment: Salesforce is magic at times and blackbox. So that is behavior (which I confirmed in my devorg as well), that is how Salesforce works. This is TIL for me and would cause so many data sync integrations. You should consider to file a bug with your sfdc service rep is you have support access.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you!